# Find new window dialogs automatically

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto, gui-testing

Let's say that I open up some word file with a macro that opens up a dialog with some buttons.

Is there a way to find those buttons automatically and press them (when having only the PID)?
Currently, I'm using pywinauto to automate the GUI testing. If there's a way to do it with pywinauto that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using MS Word app, it should be possible using `backend="uia"` from pywinauto. If Inspect.exe can see the dialog and buttons you need, it's possible to automate by pywinauto. See the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) to learn more about backends and the core concept.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov What I'm trying to do is find these controls automatically. Something that I don't see in pyautowin. I'm opening many documents and one of them can open up some random dialog which I want to be able to see and automatically press the "Ok" buttons for example.

Comment: What do you mean when saying "Something that I don't see in pywinauto"? What the steps are you doing to see them? Could you please edit your question with some code snippet, detailed output and/or screenshots?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Maybe I didn't explain myself properly, I need a generic way to find buttons in some random window that can show up.. The buttons could be "OK", "Next", "Accept", etc... I didn't find a generic way to do this in pyautowin because it must be something specific (like app.SpecificDialog.OK.click())

Comment: In this case you can use `app.windows()` to enumerate top-level windows and `app.windows()[0].children()` to enumerate immediate children or `.descendants()` for the whole subtree. Is this what you need?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Yeah I think this is it.. I can use this to also find all the window's buttons, right?

Comment: Correct. `children()` and `descendants()` can enumerate all controls visible to used backend (some modern UI can be not visible to `backend="win32"` so you have to switch to `backend="uia"` while instantiating `Application` object). This is all described in the first link I posted here.

Comment: The children and descendants methods are not described in the link, but that's ok.. You can post this as the answer

Comment: Yes, I mean backends are described. Maybe it's good idea to mention these 2 methods in this guide as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize all the comments:

It's possible to enumerate all the windows and their controls using methods `.windows()` (for top-level windows), immediate `.children()` and all the `.descendants()` (the whole subtree as a plain list). You can even filter children and descendants by class_name, control_type, content_only and/or title.

Example:

```
print(app.windows()[0].descendants(control_type='Edit'))
```

Comment: Thanks! I Wish it was more documented in pywinauto.readthedocs.io